# Why we cannot change the template category from OpenShift console?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools, openshift-enterprise

We have template with **tags=database,redis** but this is not listing under database catagory; instead listing under "Other" category. I saw below method but not sure this is correct way for production clusters. 
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/install_config/web_console_customization.html#configuring-catalog-categories

And do we have any cli method other than above javascript method?

**Update:**
My bad, I have copied details from wrong node. Correct details below.

```
# oc v3.9.41
kubernetes v1.9.1+a0ce1bc657
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEGO

Server https://cluster01.example.com:8443
openshift v3.9.41
kubernetes v1.9.1+a0ce1bc657
```

*Ignore below item; it was wrong*

```
# oc version
oc v3.6.173.0.129
kubernetes v1.6.1+5115d708d7
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEGO

Server https://cluster01.example.com:443
openshift v3.6.173.0.129
kubernetes v1.6.1+5115d708d7*
```

Comment: You are reading 3.9 docs, not 3.6 docs. Because of changes made with respect to service catalog and template service broker in newer version, you would be better to look at the docs for the exact version you are using as things may not be the same.

Comment: Perhaps try using `datastore` instead of `database`? `database` is the alias, so it _should_ work, but can't hurt to try it differently, https://github.com/openshift/origin-web-console/blob/master/app/scripts/constants.js#L538

Comment: Also, maybe try removing `redis`, could be causing issues

Comment: You can look on your cluster manually by opening a browser console window, and typing `window.OPENSHIFT_CONSTANTS`, the category list should be under `CATALOG_CATEGORIES`. Again, this may be different for your version

Comment: Finally, make sure you're using the `tags` under `annotations` not `labels`. https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/dev_guide/templates.html#writing-description

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton my mistake, 
wrong details copied. Actually its 3.9

# oc version
oc v3.9.41
kubernetes v1.9.1+a0ce1bc657
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEGO

Comment: @WillGordon I have tried that, but didnt work :(

Comment: @WillGordon also I have verified that. tags are under Annotations

Comment: Hi guys! Its possible to make a custom category?